# How do I Allow my Azure Web App to accept logins from multiple email domains (Allow both Internal org @myBuisness.com and external @outlook.com)

Tags: asp.net, azure, email, outlook, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use Azure Active directory to manage logins to my web app but the problem is at the moment it only accepts users to have the same company email domain as the site. I have looked into 'multi-tenant' and have turned it on but it doesn't seem to make a difference and allow any email to sign in. I think that's what it is supposed to do but correct me if I am wrong.

I was just wondering if there is an easy way to do it, as I can't seem to find anything about allowing multiple email domains. This is probably cause I am not searching for the problem properly but I can't figure out what to look for.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When an app is single tenant mode, it means that only users who are in your Azure tenant's AD can login and use that app. However if you switch the toggle to multi-tenant mode. This means that anyone in any Azure tenant can login to their tenant and use your app. Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview) for how to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern .

But in your scenario , microsoft accounts should be able to access your application . If you want to enable local azure ad accounts(organization/work accounts) and microsoft accounts(@outlook.com),you can try  :

1. In Azure AD v1.0 , you could add the microsoft accounts as external users(New guest user) , then microsoft accounts could use your application .
2. You could use Azure AD V2.0 . Azure AD V2.0 supports both personal Microsoft accounts and work accounts from Azure Active Directory . Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview) for more details about Azure AD V2.0 Endpoint .